# changing from WillPopScope to PopScope throws exception of '!_debugLocked': is not true

Tags: flutter, navigator

I'm changing my code from `WillPopScope` to `PopScope` to capture pressing of the back button. I need to display a dialog before going back to previous screen. So, I need to issue `Navigator.pop` twice, one to dismiss dialog and other one going back to previous screen. The code below works fine with `WillPopScope` but an error of  `'!_debugLocked': is not true` is thrown when I change it to `PopScope` since `WillPopScope` is depreciated.

```
// return WillPopScope(
return PopScope(
    canPop:true,
    onPopInvoked: (bool didPop) async{
  //  onWillPop: () async {
    if (vStatus[1] && !vStatus[2]) {
      _showMaterialDialog(context, 1);
    }
    return Future.value(true);
  },
  child: Scaffold(
   …….


void _showMaterialDialog(BuildContext context, int opt) {
  showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title:  Text(getTextTitle(opt),style:TextStyle(fontFamily: 'DancingScriptBold',color:Colors.blue, fontSize: 20.0)),
          content: Text(getTextContent(opt),
              style: const TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'DancingScriptBold', color:Colors.blue,fontSize: 20.0),
              ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            TextButton(
                onPressed: ()  {
                    Utils.saveVideo().then((value) async {
                     if(value!) {
                        vStatus[2] = true;
                    }
                  });
             
                    Navigator.of(context).pop(); //dismiss dialog
                    Navigator.of(context).pop(); //go back to previous screen             
            
                },
                child: const Text(
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'DancingScriptBold', color:Colors.blue,fontSize: 20.0),
                    'Yes')),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
              
                 Navigator.of(context).pop(); //dismiss dialog
                 Navigator.of(context).pop(); //go back to previous screen  
               
                }
              },
              child: const Text(
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: 'DancingScriptBold',color:Colors.blue, fontSize: 20.0),
                  'No'),
            )
          ],
        );
      });
}
```

Appreciate any feedback!

Answer (score 13):

According to release notes [https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/android-predictive-back#migrating-a-back-confirmation-dialog:~:text=route%20transitions.%0A%7D-,Migrating%20a%20back%20confirmation%20dialog,-WillPopScope%20was%20sometimes](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/android-predictive-back#migrating-a-back-confirmation-dialog:%7E:text=route%20transitions.%0A%7D-,Migrating%20a%20back%20confirmation%20dialog,-WillPopScope%20was%20sometimes)

You can use the below code

```
  PopScope(
  canPop: false,
  onPopInvoked: (bool didPop) async {
    if (didPop) return;
    final NavigatorState navigator = Navigator.of(context);
    if (vStatus[1] && !vStatus[2]) {
      await _showMaterialDialog(context, 1);
    }
    navigator.pop();
  },
),
```

Comment: Did you notice that the `onPopInvoked` method executes twice?

Comment: It works by adding`if(didPop) return;` Thanks.

Comment: @jdevp2 no it doesn't, if you add a breakpoint on the if condition, you can see that the method gets invoked twice. Once for `didPop` = `false` and once for `didPop` = `true`. I just would like to understand if that intentional or not, because the previous `WillPopScope` didn’t had this behavior.

Comment: @NickolasdeLucaAlberton I'm working on very similar code* and yes, I do notice that onPopInvoked is executed twice. I don't understand how didPop can ever be true, if the canPop property is false! In any case, simply adding that one line also allowed my code to run without any obvious signs of a problem.
* The code is from the Academind course "Flutter & Dart - The Complete Guide [2023 Edition]"

Comment: Yes, `onPopInvoked` is executed twice, because the `navigator.pop()` triggers it again. In the second execution `didPop` is `false`, so `navigator.pop()` is not called again. As far as I understand it, the parameter `canPop` is only taken into account on a `maybePop()` command (which is used by the native back button or gesture). When a simple `pop()` command is used, the `canPop` parameter is ignored and `didPop` in the callback is `true`. The docs on this should be improved and mention this explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware of the feature that
FlutterFragmentActivity does not kill app by back -  unlike FlutterActivity

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/117061